# How do I remove duplicates from a list?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies all "not blank" cells from Column "B4: B50" and pastes it into Cell "B4" in the "Consolidated Tracker" worksheet.

This returns duplicate data which I'd like to remove.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated Tracker")

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        Last = WorksheetFunction.Max(4, DestSh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        sh.Range("B4:B50").Copy DestSh.Range("B" & Last)
    End If
Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

I was trying to adapt [Range.RemoveDuplicates Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) by adding:

`DestSh("B4:B10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes`

After the `For Each` loop remove the duplicates before trying to figure out how to then remove the blank spaces I assume it'll leave behind.

I'm getting a

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

I think this means I can't use DestSh as Worksheet. I assume Worksheet doesn't support RemoveDuplicate.

Comment: Can you try `DestSh.Range("B4:B10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes` ?

Comment: You can remove duplicates using the ribbon command (under Data). If you need to automate, record a macro of yourself removing the duplicates, and then it should be straightforward to adjust the generated code to your needs. More on that: see: [**Recording a Macro to Generate Code**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) as well as [**Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros).

Comment: @SJR Nothing happened, no errors no change to F8. Same as before, list with duplicates.

Comment: @SJR actually my bad, it's removing some of the duplicates, but not all of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a single column of data try:

```
DestSh.Range("B4:B10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Wait no, it removes SOME of the duplicates. But not all of them oddly.

Comment: @L23P  We are at least making some progress!  carefully review you data.

Comment: Data is being collected from another macro, nothing manual. Macro grabs row `B1:L1` from every single workbook within a given folder. The data in this row is produced by formula and is all standardised. No free text anywhere, all input is done via drop down lists. When I step through I can see some data remove but others remain. Take "Asureforce" 4 instances of it and 4 instances remaining after execution.

Comment: I've replaced all my data with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` to test. So 5 sheets with 1-5 as data. Totally 25 cells worth of data. I'm looking at two `1` after running the macro. It goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5.

Comment: @L23P  Is it possible that there are **trailing spaces** after some of the data???

Comment: Yes but it's the same data source, so the trailing space would be replicated across any instance.

Comment: Spoke too soon, still looking at `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5`

Comment: Oh wait, `Header:=xlYes` is causing this issue! Swapped to no, test data is not working. It works! Issue is data, I'll see about tidying it up.